# MySQL - Single criteria for multiple columns within single table - MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I would appreciate any help creating this query. I will make a simple example of what I want to do. I have a table (named t1) that is structurally similar to the following:

```
id   f_name   l_name   address
----------------------------------
 1   alpha    beta     city phi
 2   gamma    beta     city beta
 3   alpha    lambda   city sigma
 4   beta     omega    city beta
```

I want to find the data that contain predetermined criteria. These criteria apply to all columns in the table.

For example I want to find data that contains the word 'beta' on the table. I use this query before, but didn't work.

```
SELECT * 
FROM t1 
WHERE id LIKE '%criteria%' 
   OR f_name LIKE '%criteria%' 
   OR l_name LIKE '%criteria%'
```

I think I need to do a sub-query of some sort. But really don't know how to proceed, Thank you.

Comment: "didn't work" is very vague. How did it not work? Did it give you an error message or did you computer catch on fire?

Comment: i'm suspecting that your id column is not an alphanumeric column, try excluding that column from your where clause. Also if possible, post any error message that you get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it does not matter for you, which column satisfies your criterion, the simplest way I can see is to concatenate all the columns like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM t1
WHERE CONCAT(id, f_name, l_name, .....) LIKE '%criteria%'
```

The above query will be equivalent to specifying many LIKE conditions with OR operator.
Moreover, it will avoid errors in case your columns are of different datatypes, because CONCAT makes automatic conversion

Comment: However, it can cause a problem when f_name is "XXX cri" and l_name is "teria XXX" as that would give a false positive.

Comment: Well, there exists a probability, but since I have no any statistics about real data, it is hard to provide a universal solution. Any kind of separator, let it be " ", "@" or something else that is not used in the columns' values can be used to get rid of the problem you have mentioned

Comment: Sure @Lesya, your solution is cromulent, but I'm just pointing it out so the limitations/shortcomings of this solution are known. I agree that in most cases, a false positive is unlikely, and can be fixed by adding a separator character not in "criteria".

Answer (score 0):

Hello I recreated your data table and the statement executed with out error. 
I think you might just have a spelling error somewhere.